# How does the amount of open APE (Ajax Push Engine) channels affect the performance?

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, socket.io, ape

I am developing a web application which follows the principle of responsivness. Every information currently visible on screen gets automatically updated if there is a change of any user - in real time.

I use APE (Ajax Push Engine) in combination with Django to submit the needed information to all users which currently have a page open. The information can be related to specific instances of objects, which could cause a large amount of open channels per user. I am talking about **a maximum of 100 open channels**.

### 1. Would this amount affect performance?

### 2. Is this good design or should i strive to create as few channels as possible?

### 3. Is APE a good choice or should i switch to node.js + Socket.IO? How measures the performance in contrast to APE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chose to switch to SockJS, see this question:

[python Socket.IO client for sending broadcast messages to TornadIO2 server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10950365/python-socket-io-client-for-sending-broadcast-messages-to-tornadio2-server)

Why? Because:

- SockJS is more reliable and stable than Socket.IO and APE
- Same for performance (as far as i know)
- SockJS has broader communication protocol support than APE
- APE server needs more configuration
- No Flash requirements